# Hold on not working with ezplot3

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm not sure why the hold on is not working in this example.

```
syms t1 t2 t3
line1 = [0,0,0] + t1*[0,0,1];
line2 = [1,0,0] + t2*[0,0,1];
line3 = [0,1,0] + t3*[0,0,1];

hold on 
ezplot3(line1(1),line1(2),line1(3))
ezplot3(line2(1),line2(2),line2(3))
ezplot3(line3(1),line3(2),line3(3))
hold off
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

I found a clue to this [here](http://www-users.math.umd.edu/~jmr/241/lines_planes.html):

> We should point out that doing things this way with ezmesh and ezplot3, it's necessary to plot first the line and then the plane. **The reason is that the code for ezplot3 is written in such a way as to undo the effect of any previously issued hold on command**. Of course one can get around this by using plot3 instead of ezplot3...

See also [here](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/answers/18962-hold-on-not-working-with-ezplot3). It seems like [plot3](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/plot3.html) is your answer.

Comment: That strange because `ezplot3('sin(t)','cos(t)','t',[0,6*pi]), hold on, h=ezplot3('cos(t)','sin(t)','t',[0,6*pi]); set(h, 'Color', 'r')` is working well.

Comment: @Clement J. Hold on works for ezplot3 when the upper boundary is the same, like in your example.

Comment: @Ghaul: that is not the case: `syms t; ezplot3(sin(t),cos(t),t,[0,6*pi]), hold on, h = ezplot3(cos(t),sin(t),t,[0,6*pi]); set(h, 'Color', 'r')`, see my answer why..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the source code of the function to understand why:

```
>> edit( fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','symbolic','symbolic','@sym','ezplot3.m') )
```

The very first line is: `clf` which deletes all graphics objects from the current figure, including the axis contained (the HOLD function basically sets the `'NextPlot'` property of the axis). Try commenting that line...

---

Note: the reason the code given by @ClementJ. in the comment works is because it is using a different EZPLOT3 function. Its calling the regular function not the version used with symbolic objects as in your example:

```
>> which -all ezplot3
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\toolbox\matlab\specgraph\ezplot3.m
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\@sym\ezplot3.m  % sym method
```

In fact the symbolic function ends up calling the regular EZPLOT3 eventually..